# Changing index in summation

Tags: summation

This question seems simple but it's been eating me for 20 mins. on a book I seen something like this :
$$
\sum_{k=8}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-1}\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{7}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{j}
$$
Could anyone tell me why the above step is valid, I understand the $\frac{1}{6}$ part but not the $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{7}$ part. It is from a probability book so conceptually I know this gives the right answer. please help, thank you very much

Comment: Note:  in formatting parentheses if you use "\left( " and  "\right)" it will scale them up to suit the expression they contain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If in doubt, write the terms out explicitly ... lets leave the $1/6$ out 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=8}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-1} &=& \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{7} + \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{8} + \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{9} + \cdots \\
&=& \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{7} \left(1  + \frac{5}{6} + \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2} + \cdots \right) \\
&=& \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{7} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{j}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: OMG, Thank you very much !!!! I feel so dumb right now, and I guess adding 8 terms to infinity doesn't change a thing :)

Answer (score 4):

Breaking it down to simpler steps.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=8}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-1}\frac{1}{6} ~&=~ \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{7}\sum_{k=8}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-8}&&\text{distributing out constant factors}
\\[1ex]&=~ \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{7}\sum_{k-8=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-8}&&\text{preparing for substitution}
\\[1ex]&=~ \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{7}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{j}&&\text{substituting }j\text{ for }k-8
\end{align}$$